# Who sent a would-be killer in Night Watch?

Tags: terry-pratchett, discworld

In one chapter of the Discworld novel *Night Watch*, a man tries to kill Vimes from a nearby roof using a crossbow while the latter is enjoying a cocoa outside the Watch House (it makes sense in context).

Vimes is saved by a promising young Assassin, but the man's crossbow is not an assassin's weapon and Madam later remarks, "That doesn't sound like Swing".

Lord Winter has not heard of Vimes at this stage of the story and Carcer is not the type to let the dirty work to others: Do we know who sent this killer?

Comment: My favourite Discworld novel and a great excuse to read it once again :D I think the answer is mentioned, but I can't recollect it atm.

Comment: @silvith Indeed (though "This is not my cow!" Thud and Thief of Time are not far behind :))

Answer (score 3):

I just re-read the passage and the would be assassin may have been sent by the "Unmentionables." Did you catch on that the would be assassin was killed by the young Vetinari.

Comment: That's why I talk about Swing (Unmemtionables' head) and Carcer... They are the more likely suspects, but I cannot find any textual reference to support it.